# How to disable guard after uninstalling Ruby?

Tags: ruby, guard

I installed Ruby on a server (1.9.3 via RVM), set up Guard on some directories, then established I didn't need any of this anymore and uninstalled Ruby (via an RVM command).

My problem is, any directory access to the directories Guard was watching still triggers an attempt to launch Ruby (which is no longer there), therefore causing an error.

I thought that, since Guard was a Ruby gem, uninstalling Ruby would "turn off" guard. It seems there's more to it than that, and that some process still remains.

How do I kill the ghost of guard?

---

[Another thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127571/why-is-my-server-complaining-that-ruby-isnt-installed-when-browsing-omega-theme?noredirect=1#comment152611_127571) suggested I run `ps aux | grep guard` to find the PID of the guard process then kill it, but the only thing that finds is the `grep guard` itself:

```
root      6754  0.0  0.0   6384   676 pts/1    S+   13:45   0:00 grep guard
```

It seems like whatever this "ghost of guard" is, it's not called `guard`.

---

It's probably not relevant, but in case it is, guard was launched via the Drupal Drush command `drush omega-guard` which is part of the Drupal theme Omega-4, and here's an example of an error that the ghost of guard is causing (this is accessing the Centos server from windows using SFTP):

[image]

Comment: Get rid of the `|grep guard` and start looking line by line... If it's running it should be in there, might not be named how you'd expect.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping someone would know what Guard uses. I'm googling every process I don't recognise and it's taking a while. Also, if/when I do hit lucky, I'm not sure how I'd know that it's whatever Guard happens to use.

Comment: Also the only processes with start times that make sense in terms of being around when I started guard are `php-cgi` (php command line), `httpd` (apache on centos), `sshd`, and `vlogger`, none of which seem right.

Comment: Just tried rebooting - that didn't work, the ghost is still there. I think it's not a process but some config change Guard has made.

Answer (score 1):

This command should list all the processes using Linux `inotify` subsystem on which Guard is based:

```
$ ps -p `find /proc -name task -prune -o -type l -lname anon_inode:inotify -print 2> /dev/null | cut -d/ -f3`
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND                                                                                                                             
 1102 ?        Ssl    0:16 evince
 3651 ?        Ss     0:01 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
 4071 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ibus/ibus-gconf
 4075 ?        Sl     1:08 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
 4092 ?        Sl     0:18 /usr/lib/ibus-mozc/ibus-engine-mozc --ibus
 4468 ?        Ssl  188:36 skype
 4788 ?        S<l  622:27 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
 7102 pts/0    S+     0:00 inotifywait -r -m -e modify --format %f JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0/
 7998 ?        Ssl    6:53 gvim
 8549 ?        Ssl   11:11 /opt/google/chrome/chrome 
 8597 ?        Ssl  307:04 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 9459 ?        Sl    50:05 /usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 8597 true plugin
16444 ?        Ssl    1:31 gvim
16452 ?        Ssl   24:39 /home/nodakai/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-2.10.27/dropbox
24514 ?        S      0:01 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor
24527 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
32491 ?        Sl    11:10 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --splash-pipe=5
```

You might as well install Ruby and Guard again to uninstall them in a proper way.

Comment: Also, this command just gives me the error `ERROR: List of process IDs must follow -p.` (Centos SSH shell)

Comment: also `find /proc -name task -prune -o -type l -lname anon_inode:inotify -print 2> /dev/null | cut -d/ -f3` seems to find nothing

Comment: Can you run `setopt -x` to print every command you run on the Bash session?  I suspect what you call Drupal-Omega (I don't know what it is) modified your .bashrc to insert hook commands.

Comment: It's a PHP-CGI script. That's a really useful lead,  thanks, I'll investigate .bashrc